# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, kotlin

Estoy recompilando mi proyecto y al momento de ejecutar en **API 30 ejecuta sin problemas**, pero al querer **ejecutar desde API 21 tengo cierta dificultad porque se me detiene mi aplicación** por el siguiente mensaje de error.

**Mensaje de error luego de haber intentado complicar nuevamente mi aplicación**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.novotaxi.driver, PID: 4351
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.novotaxi.driver/com.innomalist.taxi.driver.activities.splash.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

**Configuración de dependencia en build Grade del proyecto la cual me funciona sin problemas al ejecutar en dispositivos de API 29**

```
dependencies {
    api 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    api 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01'
    api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'
    api 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:6.2.0'
}
```

**Archivo XML de la actividad que se intenta abrir y ocurre el error en proyecto**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fondo_novo_app">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_image"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_button"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: mmm... lo único que se me ocurre es que pruebes a borrar el drawable a ver si carga, en ese caso puede ser el formato... en la app del trabajo que está en producción ya tuvimos un problema con la splash, fallaba en algunos dispositivos y resulta que era el drawable cargado...

Comment: Por lo que mencionas parece si ser ese el inconveniente pues quito la imagen que carga en el splash y se soluciona (ya intente borrar el drawable). Sabiendo esto sigo en la búsqueda de solución de como corregir este inconveniente.

Comment: La imagen fondo_novo_app se encuentra en /drawable ? es un vector asset, un .xml podrìas compartila?

Comment: Funciono eliminando la imagen que me daba problemas ya que no estaba en mi carpeta drawable

Answer (score 0):

Como indica el LogCat, existe un problema al inflar el layout:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8:
> Error inflating class
> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

esto se puede deber a que cargas una clase o recurso que no existe, o este caso que indicas el error se muestra en cierta API o menor, lo probable es que la imagen no sea valida o que no exista.

Revisa que la imagen `fondo_novo_app` se encuentre en el directorio `/drawable` y no ùnicamente e `/drawable-v21`

Comment: Hola, cree la carpeta '/drawable-v21' y copie la imagen que estaba en '/drawable' (fondo_novo_app) pero me sigue devolviendo el mismo error.

Comment: Que tipo de imagen es fondo_novo_app? es un xml?

Comment: Es una imagen *.png que va en el fondo de inicio - login de mi app